# Which of these is most correct, and why?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

1. He called me over FaceTime
2. He called me by Facetime.
3. He called me through FaceTime.
4. He called me via FaceTime.
5. He called me with FaceTime.

FaceTime = A calling [service](http://www.apple.com/mac/facetime/) from Apple.

Comment: *He TwitFaced me*, or *he called/texted me on TwitFace*, seem to be the favourites from a straw poll just taken in our UK household.

Comment: Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.

Answer (score 2):

Facetime may be the name of the service, but it has also become the verb to describe using the service. That being the case I would recommend "he facetimed me".
This was my experience of the usage, but I checked online and found "facetimed me" gets 26,000 google hits versus 1,00 for "called me over FaceTime".

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, it's a toss-up between *via*, *with*, and maybe *over*. They all technically make sense (or at least, if I saw any of these sentences, I'd know what you were talking about) but I think those three word choices fit/flow the best. *Via* is probably my favorite.

You could try writing the sentence in different ways (or write similar sentences that convey the same concept) and use the same words, and see if they get the same idea across.

> > "We talked **via** FaceTime."
> >
> > "They were able to communicate **with** FaceTime."
> >
> > "This isn't something that should be discussed **over** FaceTime."

I think in some ways it will depend on the exact context the sentence is in. See how my *over* example is a little different than the others? Any of the choices would probably have worked, but certain words will work better in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

Since 'FaceTime' is a service (abstract or irrealis), rather than a physical thing (concrete or realis), prepositions do not have their literal meanings.  However; 'via' means 'using the pathway' and I find that the least ambiguous.